# Drupal apc module

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-modules, apc

I have deployed drupal site on my dev env and I can view the frontend of the site. The Site pages are cached using APC server cache module installed on drupal.

The Issue is that I'm not able to clear the cache using Admin Console of Drupal CMS because after login I get the error -
Fatal error: Call to undefined function apc_delete() in C:\xampp\htdocs\nrdrupaldev\sites\all\modules\apc\drupal_apc_cache.inc on line 289

As the Admin is not accessible due to the above error I tried to disable the module directly from the Database using this query - 
UPDATE system SET status='0' WHERE name='apc'

After this I also disabled the module from settings.php by removing its config settings.

But this gave me a series of errors and warnings see below image ![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is your PHP version. APC no longer works in [PHP 5.5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611676/is-apc-compatible-with-php-5-4-or-php-5-5) so you will need the [APCu extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205809/what-is-userland-caching-apcu-extension-in-php).

If you are getting an error stating that a function that belongs to APC is not defined it's safe to say that the extension is not being loaded.

I have not used the APC Drupal module for some time as I has switched my caching needs to Redis but I believe it was updated to support APCu.

Comment: i have use PHP 5.4,Please suggest me ,if you can give you email that i can mail you my whole question.my email is navjyotpankaj@gmail.com